# Check if cell value is also in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets

I have two columns that contain text. I want to fill a third column with the text that is found in both columns.

for example:

[image]

What formula can I use to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cell E2 and copied down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$7,MATCH(1,INDEX((COUNTIF($D$2:$D$7,$C$2:$C$7)>0)*(COUNTIF(E$1:E1,$C$2:$C$7)=0),),0)),"")
```